# Boss Katana 100 Backing Track from Spotify

Tags: amplifiers

I have some Backingtracks on Spotify and this runs on my computer. Now I have a Boss Katana 100 Amp and am a bit confused how I can actually playback that backing tracks from my PC to the Amp so I can join in with my connected guitar.

I also have a small Blackstar portable bluetooth amp. It's pretty simple there cause I just need to connect the bluetooth to my smartphones spotify and off it goes.

The Katana 100 does not have any bluetooth device as far as I know.

Any advice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a 1/8" Aux In input on the back of the amp. So find a 1/8" Stereo cable, and connect the other end to the source of your choice.

If you really want Bluetooth, it isn't built in. You'd need an external bluetooth receiver, which you would connect to that 1/8" input.